# How to prove a property considering Lebesgue-integrable function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, lebesgue-integral

Let $E$ be measurable function, and $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\cup\{u\}\subset L^1(E)$. Let further $$\int\limits_E |u-u_n|\,dt < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+2}}$$ and $f_n$ be simple functions.

I need to prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \int\limits_E |u_{k}-u_{k-1}|\,dt < \int\limits_E |u|\,dt + \varepsilon,$$

where $u_0=0$.

I have a problem with solving this problem:

If I represent $|u_k-u_{k-1}|=|u_k-u|+|u-u_{k-1}|$ I won't get the result I need.

If i use the fact that $u=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (u_k-u_{k-1})$, I get the inequality with the opposite sign.

Could you give me some hint?

Comment: I assume that the $u$ should be $f$ or vice-versa?

Comment: Yes, I'm just used to denote functions by $u$.

Comment: I also forgot to add that $u_n$ Are simple functions.

Comment: Can you add that to the problem?